# file list in google drive incomplete

Tags: file, listview, directory, path, last-modified

Yesterday I uploaded from  my imac (monterey) a single folder containing a set of  files  and subfolders.  When I open  google drive  the list of files on  my drive (my directory?) only shows  files  previously on the  list. The  folder uploaded is not  listed  but the content is  listed under 'recent'. The subfolders are not listed  but  the contents are  listed , Each  file shows a location (pathname?,shown  in 'location'

1. How can  I merge the recent list with the other  list?
2. how long do they stay  in 'recents'?
3. When  I  clicked on 'location' of one file the list changed to show date last modified(useful) for all the listed files . How can I get this without  clicking on location?

I was trying to transfer  files from imac (previously synced with  idrive, who are  withdrawing the 'free' backup this month) and would like to be able to see (as a directory?) all that  I have  uploaded viz:   a complete list of files and folders  at the 'top' level, and click on  a folder to get the  list of what is in the  folder or subfolder.
Eventually I also want to  synchronise with one specific folder on imac ,  mirrored with the same folder  on google drive.